# The instance variable super cannot be accessed from the definition of another instance variable

Tags: oop, ocaml

i'm trying to do some OOP in OCAML.

Here are two classes :

```ml
class virtual game_object id x y z =
    object (self)
        val id : int = id
        val x : int = x
        val y : int = y
        val z : int = z
        method get_x  = x
        method get_y  = y
        method get_z  = z
    end;;
```

```ml
 class tile id x y z tile_type =
    object(self)
        inherit game_object id x y z as super
        val tile_type : tile_type = tile_type
        val w : int = 80
        val h : int = 80
        val box : Sdl.rect = Sdl.Rect.create super#get_x super#get_y w h (* This line triggers the error *)
        method get_tile_type = tile_type
    end
    ;;
```

When I try to compile, I get this error :

```
The instance variable super cannot be accessed from the definition of another instance variable
```

I have no idea how to solve this issue. Please help? Thank you.

Comment: One way to solve it is to replace it with **method** but in this instance I want box to be an instance variable.

Comment: Consider the case when `super#get_x` is a virtual method or uses other methods of the super class that are virtual. The tile overrides or implements the virtual method and then `super#get_x` can access values in `self` that haven't been initialized yet. The type system isn't smart enough to show which super methods would be save to call so none can be called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution might be to factorize the common part of the value instance, avoid the getter of the super class, and just define the rectangle from the class arguments:

```
class tile id x y z tile_type =
  let w = 80 in
  let h = 80 in
  object(self)
    val box = Sdl.Rect.create x y w h
    inherit game_object id x y z as super
    val tile_type : tile_type = tile_type
    val w = w
    val h = h
    method get_tile_type = tile_type
end
```

If you need to access `x` and `y` through the getters, you could make `rect` mutable, initialize it to a dummy value first, and then add an initializer to set it to the correct value:

```
class tile id x y z tile_type =
  object(self)
    inherit game_object id x y z as super
    val tile_type : tile_type = tile_type
    val w = 80
    val h = 80
    val mutable box = Sdl.Rect.create 0 0 0 0
    initializer box <- Sdl.Rect.create super#get_x super#get_y w h
    method get_tile_type = tile_type
end
```